# How to use Android asset studio for action bar?

Tags: android

as provided in link http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html How to use this zip folders created by this site for styling purpose....?Can any one provide detailed step wise procedure to add this generated folder action tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new Android project (make sure that the target sdk is at least 3.x or 4.x)
2. Use the new Android project wizard to create a project similar to the one in the preview on his site (in other words, a project with an ActionBar and tabs). Or look at the listing of projects on [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect) and import one of the ActionBar projects from there.
3. Make sure the initial project by the wizard works as intended. Go ahead and run it at least once before you add anything else.
4. Download the generated zipped folder from the site
5. Unzip it
6. Cut and paste the resulting res/ folder in the root of your project (to replace the current res/ folder). If there are any file name conflicts, let the files you're cutting and pasting overwrite all the existing file names.
7. Look inside the main activity/fragment for setContentView(), the name of the main xml layout file setContentView is calling has changed over time, so you may have to change that to make sure it's calling the new main layout xml file that you've just cut and pasted.
8. Clean the code and rebuild everything.
9. If there are still errors that prevent you from compiling the project. Open the Errors View panel. Double-click on each error and try to resolve each one one at a time.

Let us know if you get stuck at any of these steps. I can add more details as needed.

Comment: I am stuck at 6th and 7th step.I have cut all the folder from res(from download zip folder) and pasted in original project res folder while copying it doesn't show any replace file pop-up.and then build and run the project but it does not replace any style of the tab or action bar.What to do?not an single error shown.what to do?Can you please upload a tutorial for this because not a single video is available on youtube please...!!!!!